# Event trigger print using VC++

Tags: visual-c++, printing

I have requirement to print log data continuously whenever an event trigger (Without showing print dialog, using default printer). Event may occur twice a second or minit or hour. Also i don`t bother about printer status. example out of paper, communication problem. Printer should not leave empty page. Example event 1 have 4 lines of data to print. While printing event 2, printer should print continuously instead of fetching next paper.

My development environment VC++ and MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a printer DC with you, if not you have create one and send file across.